# ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE returns poor image quality bitmap, where can I get the hi-res image?

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I want the good quality image to show in `ImageView` and upload to the server. I have searched the Internet, StackOverflow and GitHub, but I could not find the answer, maybe somebody knows how can fix it?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { //work android
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    imageReturnedIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);//try

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {// work every android than need click OK
      //working
        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();//convert to for bitmap that can send
        Bundle extras = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();//finish converting and copy the image
        bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");//receive image to bitmap
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

`onCreate`:

```
btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 9):

The `Intent` you send returns only low-quality picture as a small bitmap.

If you want the full-resolution image, you need to prepare the file where this image will be saved and provide all necessary information to the Camera application. The details are available at [Save the full-size photo](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) section, with all explanations and the code samples.

Comment: I don't want to save the image, but I want to send the image with a quality I take the picture.

Comment: @evgeny there are 2 reasons why you cannot, 1) it's much easier to upload the file 2) `Intent` can hold only so much data, not enough for the hi-resolution picture.